# Как из Map добавить значения в List с помощью Stream и Lamda

Tags: java, потоки-данных, for

Мне нужно добавить значения по ключу (field) из Map в List. С помощью обычного for проблем не возникает, но я никак не могу это сделать с помощью Stream and Lamda выражений. Вот код. Я пробовал сделать через forEach но также потерпел неудачу.

```
public ObjectExemple fieldValue(String field, String... actualValue) {

    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

    for (int i = 0; i < expectedValue.length; i++) {
        Map<String, Object> listItem = actual.getValue().get(i);
        list.add(listItem.get(field));
    }
    
    Map<String, Object> listItem = actual.getValue().iterator().next();
    List<Object> list1 = listItem.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals(field)).map(Map.Entry::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(list1);
```

Comment: А что именно не работает?